# MySQL intersection on one table with time type

Tags: mysql, time

I've a table with 4 columns: id (int), name (varchar), timefrom (time), timeuntil (time)

Now I would like to have all combinations where they have an intersection on the timefrom to timeuntil.

My current solution is that I load all the records and loop it in php for every full hour... but this costs me much performance.

Any Ideas, is this possible to solve in a Select?

I want to know which presences are sharing the same timefrom, timeuntil As an example:

```
#1 / whole day / 06:00:00 / 18:00:00 
#2 / morning   / 07:00:00 / 12:00:00 
#3 / afternoon / 13:00:00 / 18:00:00
```

I would like to have the result:

```
#1, #2, #3   (the whole day shares the times with morning, afternoon) 
#2, #1       (the morning shares the times with the whole day) 
#3, #1       (the afternoon shares the times with the whole day)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "intersection"? Do you have a fixed timestamp that you want to compare with the `(timeform, timeuntil)` range? Or you want to compare the ranges between rows? If you added a few sample rows and the expected outcome, it would be much better,.

Comment: Questions like this are frequently best understood with DDL (CREATE TABLE blah (field1 type1, field2....)); and DML (INSERT INTO blah VALUES(value1, value2...); Then, from that data, provide us with the result you want and the logic you used to get it. p.s. welcome to the forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need a self join with a non-equality condition that checks for overlaping ranges. The output can be in different formats. Depending on your needs, the easiest would be a 2-column output:

```
SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id
FROM calendar AS a
  JOIN calendar AS b
    ON  a.id <> b.id
    AND a.timefrom < b.timeuntil
    AND b.timefrom < a.timeuntil 
ORDER BY a.id, b.id ;
```

Output would be (2 columns):

```
#1    #2   (the whole day shares the times with morning) 
#1    #3   (the whole day shares the times with afternoon) 
#2    #1   (the morning shares the times with the whole day) 
#3    #1   (the afternoon shares the times with the whole day)
```

To get the rows combined, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT a.id AS a_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(b.id ORDER BY b.id SEPARATOR ' ') AS b_ids
FROM calendar AS a
  JOIN calendar AS b
    ON  a.id <> b.id
    AND a.timefrom < b.timeuntil
    AND b.timefrom < a.timeuntil 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id ;
```

Output (2-columns):

```
#1    #2 #3   (the whole day shares the times with morning, afternoon) 
#2    #1      (the morning shares the times with the whole day) 
#3    #1      (the afternoon shares the times with the whole day)
```

If you want one row per `a.id` and multiple columns, you'll need dynamic SQL.